# What are the basics needed to learn Raspberry Pi?

Tags: raspbian

I am new to the raspberry pi concept so I would like to know about all the basic requirements that are needed to learn raspberry pi

Comment: You could search the internet for books, like "Learning Raspberry Pi" - You can find paid ebooks, free books, forums, tutorials, blogs, articles, example code, different operating systems, embedded electronics, home automation, etc.

Comment: Learning the Pi is a very vague phrase and is highly dependent on context. How do you plan to use the Pi? Do you want to learn the Linux OS, system administration, programming in Python, Lisp, Racket, Java, C, C++ etc. DBA administration, web development, electronics, hacking and security? It would help if you expanded your question to clarify hat you want to learn.

Answer (score 4):

> What are the basics needed to learn...?

Well I'll go with an open mind, the joy of learning new things, and a certain amount of stubbornness to overcome obstacles that *will* arise.

Luckily there are plenty of resources to get you started:

- the [MagPi](https://www.raspberrypi.org/magpi/) (over 50 issues so far loaded with tutorials and projects)
- [Kolbans free ebook](https://leanpub.com/pi)
- [our blog](https://raspberrypise.tumblr.com/)
- various tutorials on the web
- this branch of StackExchange for all specific questions that might arise

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of web sites, tutorials and books dedicated to the Pi.  I would just buy one, find a decent tutorial site and start playing with it.  You could also go to adafruit.com and search for "pi starter pack" to get started.

Comment: thank you for the info, can you suggest me a good book?